# get numbers from OracleDataReader

Tags: c#, oracle

i was trying to fetch data from a oracal database one of the table's column is a NUMBER(4,0). how can i fetch this data type from database in c#...

this is the sample code which i was trying to compile

```
 ArrayList ListofSaleno = new ArrayList();
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=orcl;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=thara;password=12";
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select saleno from transaction_file_com01 where selrcd ='"+userID+"'", con);
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    ListofSaleno.Add(dr.GetInt32(o));//Error line
                }
            }
            dr.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            return (ListofSaleno);
```

but it throws an error..
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

any one who can help me??? thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you should properly type your list. Instead of `ArrayList`, use `List<decimal>`.

An Oracle `number` is represented as at `decimal` in C#, so use:

```
dr.GetDecimal(0)
```

Depending on the scale and precision of the data returned, you might need (not in this case) `dr.GetOracleNumber` and extract the value yourself.

Comment: thank you.... :) it is working now i need extract date... is it normal c# Date Obj......

Comment: If you use `GetDateTime` it is.